# Multi-Class Text Classification with Negative Training Examples

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification

I have a problem similar to the questions
[Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255603/how-do-i-use-negative-examples-in-addition-to-positive-ones-for-training-a-mul) and [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310344/how-to-include-negative-examples-in-multi-class-classification).

In short, for a multi-class text classification problem, how to incorporate samples where I only know the classes they do ***not*** belong to?

In a typical text classification problem, the training data would look something like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Sample 1       |     Class A      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Sample 2       |     Class B      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Sample 3       |     Class C      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Sample 4       |     Class B      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         ...         |        ...       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to tell the classifier that Sample X does not belong to Class B.

I am using a BERT-based text classifier. Are there neural-based approaches that can handle this case? If not, are there recommended practices to make use of such negative samples?

Any feedback is appreciated.